# Algorithm - worst case time complex considers space complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

To solve a particular problem, 2 algorithms are available -

1. Algo 1 takes O(n) time and O(n) space in worst case
2. Algo 2 takes O(nlogn) time and O(1) space in worst case

What is worst case time complexity to solve the problem out of algo 1,2 and why?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking which worst case is worse? Alg2's worst-case time is worse, because nlogn > n.

Edit (to answer the question raised in comments):

If you're asking what is the best worst case? Alg1's worst-case time is best, again because nlogn > n.

Comment: Why don't we choose least complexity out of available worst case complexities ? What will happen if same problem can be solved using algo 3 with n^2 time complexity . This way we can have n no of algorithm with different worst case complexity.

Comment: You should indeed choose the algorithm with the lower worst case complexity. But that's not the question you asked. If you're asking what is the best worst-case time complexity out of algo 1,2, then the answer is indeed Algo 1 (for the same reason: nlogn > n)